# Check user roles using two tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to display users with a specific role. I have three tables.

user_roles table

| role_id | User_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |

roles table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | chair |
| 2 | doctor |

users table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | test |
| 2 | user |

The roles table have a foreign key with role_id in user_roles table.

I want to fetch users in user table where role  = doctor.

I have two models

User model
Roles model

`

```
 public function showDoctor ()
    {
         $users = User::all();

        <-- I want to return the code here to for the users -->
        
        return $users;
    }
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define the relation between users and roles in User model

```
function Roles(){
   return $this->belongsToMany(Role:class);
}
```

and you can have your condition like this

```
User::whereHas('Roles' , function($role){

  $role->where('name' , 'doctor');

});
```